# How to stop Brittany from expanding brackets for alignment

Tags: haskell, formatting, brackets

I'm using Brittany to format my Haskell code. How can I configure Brittany to keep alignment, but not expand out square brackets to fit alignment.

I.E. what I have is this:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' []       = []
reverse' [x     ] = [x]
reverse' (x : xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

When what I would like is this:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' []       = []
reverse' [x]      = [x]
reverse' (x : xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

Thanks!